# Cannot query records on models with changes error message

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an edit form that upon submitting I get the error 'Cannot query records on models with changes.'

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table Not Updating With Manual Save Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288895/table-not-updating-with-manual-save-mode)